# Why not use SO for the SO Podcast

Tags: feature-request, podcast

Why aren't you guys using SO as more of a medium to get content from your users? Just do a question every week (like on Sunday) as the Official Podcast question of the week. Mark it a CW and ask users to post (as answers) what they want you guys to talk about or answer on the show.

Then when you guys are recording. Lock the question and answer the top items in a section of the show.

Comment: Shouldn't be the poll on MSO? It's so meta ;-)

Comment: So or MSO, whatever the devs feel is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this, you might be able to use it as a queue with the highest voted (CW of course) answer being the priority on the show and then subsequently deleted once aired.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a similar thing to get the question to talk about too - there are likely to be things (some of the more subjective ones) people would like to hear Joel and Jeff talk about.